# Simple alternative to Translation Manager?

Tags: cme, translation-manager

We have a pure Tridion installation, without Translation Manager.I found quite frustrating and hard maintaining multiple language sites through its normal GUI. Searching for content components and localizing them, extracting textual content to provide to translation companies(eighter manual translation or machine) and then reformatting the content of components, publishing them, etc. Is not a user freindly way to do this.how others are doing this? Which tools are used or built to optimize these steps and automatize these processes?

We have built core of an application which could actually be an alternative to Translation Manager. All this running on client side as a simple application with an OS friendly GUI interface.
Functionalities covering or planning to cover in our tool:

1. Login/authorization to Tridion
2. selecting a page in a publication and by hitting a button in our client tool, all the necessary content components are being extracted from Tridion - This will be the source of the translation
3. Extracted content component XHTML/XML data can be saved easily to a local or network folder into filex
4. Content components in the destination publication will be automatically localized
5. Extracted XHTML will be sent for tranlsation
6. After we get back the translated XHTML files we import them back to Tridion - it will automatically update the previousily localized components in the destination publication
7. Will be able to publish all the necessary components, page component, etc. - by hitting a button after import of translated content is done

All this is solved on client side, thinking about and planning additional functionalities, optimizations of the above process. Also thinking about attaching it to a simple database, but depends what we may need.

Just trying to build something as a cheaper and more simple alternative to Translation Manager. Anyone else with similar goals, or is there something similar "tool" available already?

We didn't change anything on Tridion server, we are planning to achieve this only by running a client side application and doing bulk of actions according to our needs via its GUI.

Thanks,
bvl

Comment: I am a little unclear as to exactly what you are asking in this question. Are you trying to find out if there are alternatives to Translation Manager available or are you trying to find out if people might be interested in the solution you built? If you are trying to find out the latter, this probably is not a good venue for your question. Maybe you can edit your post to clarify what your question is?

Comment: if we have a pure Tridion installation, without Translation Manager.I found quite frustrating and hard maintaining multiple language sites through its normal GUI. Searching for content components and localizing them, extracting textual content to provide to translation companies(eighter manual translation or machine) and then reformatting the content of components, publishing them, etc. Is not a user freindly way to do this.how others are doing this? Which tools are used or built to optimize these steps and automatize these processes? About 2nd part: where should I propose our tool? Thanks!

Comment: @BVL please edit your question and provide this information in there instead of placing it in a comment. Focus on asking a question where you need help with, rather than talking about your frustrations. Providing context to your question is okay but first and foremost you have to make the question clear which at this moment it isn't.

Comment: Thanks, Bart just edited the question...However it may be too late. :(

Comment: I (and I guess others too) still don't see what your exact question is, are you asking which tools are available to optimize translation besides TM (then why are you mentioning your tool)? or are you looking for people who are doing something similar as your tool (that is not a question which would fit this site, see the [FAQ](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask))? Unless you have a specific question on how to build your tool, but then please make clear what that exact question is. Keep in mind your question should be reasonably scoped, avoid asking a subjective question.

Comment: Both. As you said:1. which "tools" are there available besides TM, if there are ones at all? 2. The approach we were working is unique or not? I also added in first place the basic functionalities covered and required for a similar "tool". Thanks!

Comment: Then my first suggestion would be to split these two questions, but you should only ask practical, answerable questions and not chatty or open-ended ones. Your first question is one which has a very short answer: see [SDL Tridion World](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/index.aspx) there are no tools known in the community. So that is not something you need to ask. Your second one is in my opinion a chatty and open-ended question, so also not one you should ask here. My recommendation would be that you blog about your tool and let the discussion start there.

Answer (score 5):

A simple alternative to Translation Manager, that would be a human. From that point onwards it doesn't matter if that human does actual translation or is guided by tools or websites to do the actual translation, unless you are looking at costs.

SDL Translation Manager and its integration with SDL Tridion is basically a workflow tool (for efficiency and tracking) with a translation memory database plus access to translation expertise for the parts of the translation that are not (yet) stored in memory. The whole concept and idea of Translation Manager is to get *more bang for your buck* (an optimized process and buying in your translation expertise in bulk).

So if in a simple alternative you also mean a cheaper alternative, then I would say hire cheap labor that uses a free translation website. But keep in mind, going cheaper will then often mean reducing quality too. This is what you would get when you for instance use Google Translate to translate your content. It doesn't cost much, but the translations aren't really good either.

Comment: This is a good comment and it highlights how unclear was my first note/question here... I just wanted to optimize/automatize the content editor steps of the translation process, not to replace a whole workflow based management system of course! I think by optimizing and automatizing those editorial steps can achieve a good quality translation maintenace and decrease maintenance costs, speed up things. The quality is not only because of the tools being used, but the quality of the translation itself. Just by automatizing text extraction and import, localization of involved components helps...

Comment: TM is basically that optimization step, plus the quality of what comes from it is assured by the fact that not everything can be machine translated and even for parts that can, SDL offers translation expertise (read human interaction by translators) to improve the outcome. Now I'm not trying to sell you SDL Translation Manager, but as explained, the concept of it is to deliver you a reduce on translation costs, so trying to build something cheaper will mean you have to drop something, which probably will be quality. The costs of TM are not just in the tooling, it is the complete package.

Comment: I understand and as I said, not planning to cover 100% all the steps and functionalities provided by Translation Manager, just was interested about how others may solved this and optimize above processes, without Translation Manager. Quality can be definded, the major question is: what do we really need to accomplish our processes according to our needs, which functionalities are really mandatory? Of course there must be also a balance between functionalities quality and costs. But all depends on the expectations/requirements and **budget**...

Comment: Looking at your requirements I don't consider your solution a simple alternative and doubt it would become cheaper, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: Bart, I would appreciate your note regarding my latest question regarding how Translation Manager would behave in some scenarios, when there are some non-compatible states found between content components and schemas: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3463/consequences-of-schema-changes-translation-manager Thanks in advance! bvl

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do translation in an external application you should use SDL Language Weaver or Google Translate or any other translation service.

SDL Language Weaver is not free and you may need to contact the SDL sales team to acquire a license. SDL Language Weaver will provide you a set of REST APIs that can be used by your application in order to translate content. It comes with 2 APIs a Synchronous and an Asynchronous API, you can use the synchronous for short amounts of text and the asynchronous one to large amount of text.

Comment: Sorry If I was not clear. SDL Language weaver is a pioneer in statistical machine translation service. What we were up to: to create a software tool to make the automatic steps described above to automatically extract text/xhtml content from Tridion and provide these files in a ZIP or XML. This is a tool we are working on... The intention of my quiestion was are there other software tools available which do the same job, without need for Translation Manager of SDL Tridion?We prefer manual/quality translation by the way. But the extraction and import and localization automatization is our goal.

Comment: It seems to be a custom developed solution, you will need to develop that client side tool and translate the content as I have described in this answer or using any other translation tool.

Comment: Yes, we have it's core functionalities already. Just wanted to know if there are others too doing the same or not. Thanks!